# Не могу закрыть сокет под Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, сокет

Есть программа на питоне. Слушаю сокет (запускаюсь из-под рута). При первом запуске всё проходит гладко. Во время выполнения программа падает. И второй раз послушать сокет я уже не могу. Система говорит, что порт занят. Т.е., вероятно, сокет где-то в фоне висит.

Вероятно, я как-то неправильно закрываю сокет. `close()` - это не решение. Наверное, его как-то нужно удалять, или ещё что-то с ним делать.

Код:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket


print("python: start")

# Сервер для браузера
print('python: Test 0')
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080)) # Падает здесь
```

Ошибка:

```
python: start
python: Test 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mapsfullsearch/src/estimation/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
^CMakefile:130: recipe for target 'estimation' failed
make: *** [estimation] Interrupt
```

Comment: Он освободится через некоторое время (я не помню точно семантику, но, кажется, ОС оставляет grace period, чтобы все подчистить). Если не изменяет память, SO_REUSEPORT позволит захватить порт сразу же. Я это все помню очень туманно, и изучал на заре юности, поэтому в целом могут быть какие-то ошибке в описании выше.

Comment: Можете дать команду `netstat -na | grep :8080` после завершения программы. Вполне возможно вы увидите подвисшие соединения в состоянии, скорее всего FIN_WAIT. пока все такие "соединения" не исчезнут открыть порт заново не выйдет. close() закрывает слушающий сокет, но если были открыты соединения (у них свои сокеты) то стороны должны обменяться закрывающими пакетами (FIN), а если не были корректно закрыты все соединения и они не были применены (реальное закрытие происходит через некоторое время) то и обмена FIN не будет, будут ожидаться таймауты

Comment: Для ускорения закрытия соединений, по крайне мере в C (как в питоне не знаю) перед close всех сокетов (рабочих, слушающий тут не причем) рекомендуется выполнять `shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR)` для сброса всех буферов и отправки FIN

Comment: [`sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380198/4279)

Comment: @Mike, нужно было добавить `socket.close()`. Но это не решает проблему аварийного прерывания пользователем `KeyboardInterrupt`. `netstat -na | grep :8080` не помогает. Если посмотреть его через `nc`, то ок. Порт юзается. Но не `netstat`.

Comment: @Etki, что мне делать с SO_REUSEPORT?

Comment: @jfs, ваша команда сработала. Но ёе глубинный смысл я не понимаю. Опять же, она не решит вопрос пользовательским прерыванием программы, т.е. `Ctrl+C`. Можно попробовать заюзать исключения. Но в этом случае finally отрабатывает не каждый раз.

Comment: Посмотреть man socket, там описаны все опции.

Comment: @hedgehogues: *"Можно попробовать заюзать исключения. Но в этом случае finally отрабатывает не каждый раз."* --**неверно**. `finally` работает как для исключений вообще (иначе что эта конструкция по вашему вообще делает) так и для Ctrl+C (KeyboardInterrupt исключение) в частности. 2- чтобы узнать что такое `SO_REUSEADDR`  и в каких случаях эту опцию обычно используют, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убить все процессы на HOST(ubuntu):

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:HOST | xargs kill -9
```

P.S. Та ошибка что у вас в посте возникла из-за того что питон не может открыть порт так как он уже кем-то занят. "socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, что он кем-то занят. Но netstat его (этого кого-то не видит). Можно посмотреть наличие процесса на 8080 через nc, но это не решает проблему. Боюсь, что этот вопрос перестал быть для меня актуальным. Я обошёл проблему по-другому: поставил flask и юзаю его.

Comment: Вы запускает netstat под root?